# Final Cut Pro hangs when the import screen tries to look at iPhone

Tags: iphone, macos, final-cut-pro

If I use Final Cut Pro to try and import video off of my iPhone 6s, about 1 out of every 2 or 3 times it will become Not Responsive and within a few minutes use all available system RAM and I'm forced to Force Quit the app. I have the first gen Retina 5K iMac so in general it's a powerful machine but it dies on the iPhone processing. Looking in the Console around the time of the hang I do notice a large amount of errors like this :

```
Sandbox: AssetCacheLocato(3407) deny(1) file-read-data
```

and then a path. Any thoughts on what I can do to stop the crash/hang?

Update:
Per Apple's troubleshooting steps, I tried these exact same steps in a different user account on my machine, and everything works perfectly. I've deleted all FCP preferences in Library but my normal user account is still doing this. Are there other user specific files for FCP other than those listed in the Apple Support Doc?

Comment: Can you get the videos onto the Mac via Image Capture or iTunes/iPhoto; make the import to FCP a separate process?

Comment: I'll have to try that. I'm going to edit my main question though. This behavior only happens under my user account, another account on the same machine is perfect.